# Installation of OpenSSH hangs on each windows system

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, ssh, openssh

I am sitting here in a big company with terrible restricted infrastructure.

When I execute the openssh installer as Administrator

on a VM with **windows server 2012** the executed cmd.exe hang for 10 minutes and more nothing happens. The same happens for another two windows 7 computers.

On my **own local windows 7 computer** after 5 minutes each of those 20 opened cmd windows are finished. But the first 4 minutes really nothing happens.

On my **private windows 10 computer** the whole installation takes ONE minute appr.

So I know somehow or guess its the companies crap infrastructure preventing me from doing a correct installation of openssh.

**Important**: It seems when I close the first openen CMD after a while all other cmd windows start to open and close from theirselves correctly.

Where would you start to make this work? Firewall? Anti-Virus?

I am grateful for any concrete tips!

[image]

Comment: How strick is the group policy is something in there preventing the install to access what it needs to? And by Crap infrastructure: Do you mean its just strict or not set up very well at all?

Comment: From a developer sight a restricted OR not setup very well infrastructure is crap.